# Compute the genus of a curve with a flex point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory

The genus of a smooth plane curve is $g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ and I know that if the curve has $n$ nodes the genus decreases by $n$. What happens if the curve has singular (non ordinary) points? In particular I would like to know how the genus decreases in the case of an intersection point between the Hessian and the curve. I guess I have to count it at least one but maybe more, but I can't find any reference on this. I found something about the delta-invariant but I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: A flex point is not in general a singular point - the second derivatives can vanish without the first derivatives vanishing. Look at $x^3 = y$ at the origin, for example. (This curve is smooth.) Or, another example, an elliptic curve in the projective plane has 9 flex points (if memory serves). Maybe you are thinking of cusps? Can you provide a specific example of what you are thinking about?

Comment: One way to do this is to use Hartshorne, Exercise IV.1.8(a). The idea is that taking Euler characteristics on the short exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow \nu_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}} \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{P \in X} \tilde{\mathcal{O}}_P/\mathcal{O}_P \longrightarrow 0$$ where $\nu\colon\tilde{X} \to X$ is the normalization, you get the equality $$p_a(X) = p_a(\tilde{X}) + \sum_{P \in X} \delta_P$$ where $\delta_P = \operatorname{length}(\tilde{\mathcal{O}}_P/\mathcal{O}_P)$. A node has $\delta_P = 1$, for example.

Comment: @AreaMan you're right I was thinking about cusps!